# Cannot start Grakn 1.5.7 server

Tags: vaticle-typedb

I'm new to Grakn.
After installing through `sudo apt install grakn-core-all` on my Ubuntu 16.04, and start the server by `grakn server start`, an error returned.

> Starting Storage... An error has occurred during boot-up. Please run
>   'grain server status' or check the logs located under the 'logs'
>   directory. java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException:
>   server/services/cassandra/cassandra.yaml

Grakn Core version is 1.5.7
My Java version is 1.8.0_192

This is the content of the `grakn.log` file in my `/var/log/grakn/` directory

> 2019-07-18 17:46:56,641 [main] ERROR grakn.core.daemon.GraknDaemon -
>   An error has occurred during boot-up. Please run 'grakn server status'
>   or check the logs located under the 'logs' directory.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException:
>   server/services/cassandra/cassandra.yaml  at
>   grakn.core.daemon.executor.Storage.initialiseConfig(Storage.java:133)
>     at grakn.core.daemon.executor.Storage.start(Storage.java:194)   at
>   grakn.core.daemon.executor.Storage.startIfNotRunning(Storage.java:147)
>     at grakn.core.daemon.GraknDaemon.serverStart(GraknDaemon.java:184)
>     at grakn.core.daemon.GraknDaemon.run(GraknDaemon.java:136)  at
>   grakn.core.daemon.GraknDaemon.main(GraknDaemon.java:72) Caused by:
>   java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException:
>   server/services/cassandra/cassandra.yaml  at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
>     at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
>     at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
>     at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
>     at
>   java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:434)
>     at java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Files.java:216)  at
>   java.nio.file.Files.write(Files.java:3292)    at
>   grakn.core.daemon.executor.Storage.initialiseConfig(Storage.java:130)
>     ... 5 common frames omitted

I hope someone can help me solve this problem.
Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a file ownership issue and as of Grakn Core 1.5.7, you will have to login as root and start the server:

```
$ sudo su -
$ grakn server start
```

This is a current limitation that has been tracked here: https://github.com/graknlabs/grakn/issues/5336

---

Another alternative solution that I will list here **just for informational purpose** is to update the permission of the file:

```
chmod 777 server/service/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
```

We don't recommend this method since while it will allow you to start as non-root, it changes the permission that is too permissive.

Comment: It works. Thank you ! Also, I used the command `sudo grakn server start`, which has the same meaning as yours. I also noticed that to stop the server, login as root is also required. For example, `grakn server stop` without `sudo` will run (I think) endlessly.